# Sharing routes between multiple prefixes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to cut down on the size of my routes file and re-use named routes. I have two separate areas that are authenticated and have their own specialized routes, however, both of them share a LOT of other routes in common.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    /**
     * Author routes.
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'author', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Controller@showHome']);

        // ...various routes unique to authors...

        Route::any('posts/data', ['as' => 'posts.data'])->uses('PostsController@data');
        Route::get('posts/{account?}', ['as' => 'posts.show'])->uses('PostsController@index');
        Route::get('posts/{post}/delete', ['as' => 'posts.delete'])->uses('PostsController@destroy');
        Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['parameters' => 'singular']);

        // ...lots more routes like the above shared with reviewers...
    });

    /**
     * Reviewer routes.
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'reviewer', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Controller@showHome']);

        // ...various routes unique to reviewers...

        Route::any('posts/data', ['as' => 'posts.data'])->uses('PostsController@data');
        Route::get('posts/{account?}', ['as' => 'posts.show'])->uses('PostsController@index');
        Route::get('posts/{post}/delete', ['as' => 'posts.delete'])->uses('PostsController@destroy');
        Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['parameters' => 'singular']);

        // ...lots more routes like the above shared with authors...
    });
});
```

I still need a reviewer to go to `example.com/reviewer/posts` to do all post related activities and authors to go to `example.com/author/posts`.

How can I make this a lot less verbose?

Comment: I don't get it, what's the point to have different URI that go to the exact same controller?

Comment: Trying to create a separate reviewers and authors area.

Comment: Yeah but if the controller is the same, I don't really get the point..

Comment: Probably isn't a good point. Slept on it and thinking I need to take a completely different approach to the design.

Comment: Though, don't know your entire app and all, but from my point of view, it seems pointless. Just saying. I think @SteD answered your question pretty well by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate route file e.g. `post_routes.php` and put all your shared `Post` route in there.

Include the route file

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'author', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
          require app_path('Http/post_routes.php');
    });

    /**
     * Reviewer routes.
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'reviewer', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
          require app_path('Http/post_routes.php');
    });
```